# 8 pin SOIC IC identification

Tags: identification

I have been analysing a PCB and have come across an IC I cannot seem to identify, so I am hoping someone here may be able to help. A picture of the IC is here:

[image]

Just in case people have trouble reading it, it is in an 8-pin SOIC package. The top line reads **7062**, the middle line reads **G007H** and the bottom line reads **JRC**

I have tried to find this myself, and all I can find with the 7062 reference is an AN7062 which doesn't seem to have an 8-pin variant so pretty sure it isn't that. Googling G007H doesn't throw up much else. The JRC seems to be the manufacturer from what I can gather, and using this with the 7062 throws up [THIS](https://www.y-ic.com/pdf/9973188555/NJU7062M.pdf) op amp, but I'm not 100% sure it is this as the IC next to it is a TL064I quad op-amp. There is of course every chance that it could be the IC I found, but it just doesn't seem to fit.

If anyone has any idea, and is better at Google than I, then I would be grateful if anyone is able to identify it.

Comment: Yep, looks like the Japan Radio Corporation NJU7061 op-amp.  Pin 4 is Vss which is another hint. since it's grounded on the board.

Comment: @JohnD Excellent. If you're quite sure, be sure to write an answer. If people seem to agree, I'll accept it if no alternatives are put forth. Thanks

Comment: @JohnD 7061 or is it 7062?

Comment: @jwh20 Oops, the "1" was a typo, it's the 7062, good catch!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is almost certainly the New Japan Radio Co. NJU7062 op-amp.  The op amp's pin 4 is Vss and you can see it's grounded on the PCB which helps confirm the P/N.

[Edited to correct the name of the company, thanks, Spehro.]

Comment: It's actually **New** Japan Radio Co., Ltd, which accounts for the NJ prefix. But the parts are marked with the JRC logo (JRC is the parent company of New Japan Radio).

Comment: Thanks, @SpehroPefhany, I had forgotten the evolution of JRC, answer corrected.

Comment: Accepted. Thanks to you and @SpehroPefhany. I was pretty sure it was the op-amp but it is nice to have that confirmed